# How can I call other class button - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this newCell class:

```
class newCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@IBOutlet weak var recipeImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var recipeTitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var favoriteButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func favoriteAction(sender: AnyObject) {


}
```

In the HomeViewController, I use this newCell class as a prototype cell for my table view. It is working fine for texts and images. My doubt is, how can I handle a button of this prototype cell in my HomeViewController?
For example, I would like the button to change its image according to the array passed.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   var recipesFeed = PFQuery(className: "Recipe")

    recipesFeed.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let recipes = objects {

        self.recipes.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.recipeImages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.isFavorite.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)


            for recipe in recipes{

                self.recipes.append(recipe["title"] as! String)
                self.recipeImages.append(recipe["image"] as! String)
                self.isFavorite.append(recipe["isFavorite"] as! Int)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }

    }
```

}

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("prototypeCell") as! newCell

 images[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (image, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: image!){

            myCell.recipeImage.image = downloadedImage

        } else {

            myCell.recipeImage.image = UIImage(named: "background_recipe_image.png")
        }


    }

    myCell.recipeTitle.text = recipes[indexPath.row]
    //begin what I try and doesn't work
    myCell.favoriteAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if isFavorite[indexPath.row] == 1 { 
      if let image = UIImage(named: "star vector.png") {

        myCell.favoriteButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)


    }

    } else {

    if let image = UIImage(named: "star vector blank.png") {

        myCell.favoriteButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

    }
    }
    }
    //end what I try and doesn't work
    return myCell
}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense: `myCell.favoriteAction(sender: AnyObject) {` The declaration for `favoriteAction` is in the `newCell` class already. That's where the code goes for what should happen when the user taps the Favorite button.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, I am quite new at that. So how can the code in newCell change this button's image according to an array from HomeViewController? Is that possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code for the HomeViewController? (or at least part of it). @RafaelDontalGonçalez

Comment: @Ike10, the second piece of script above is my HomeViewController. Before that part, I am just populating "isFavorite"array. Any ideas?

Comment: How is your `isFavorite` array populated @RafaelDontalGonçalez? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: Yes, sure. I edited above. It's in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: So to clarify, you want the button's image to change for its `.Normal` state when pressed if the value at the index of isFavorite (an array of strings) is equal to the value "1"? (you compare it to the number  1 so I assume you meant to compare it to the string "1"). @RafaelDontalGonçalez. If this is the case I can help you.

Comment: Exactly, @Ike10. You were right, I edited te code to be an array of Ints so that I can compare with numbers. Thanks for your help, I am looking forward to seeing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my method for accessing the `isFavorited` array in the HomeViewController is to use a delegation pattern with two protocols.

```
protocol hasFavBtn {

  var delegate: FavBtnDelegate! { get set }
  var delegateTableView: UITableView! { get set }

}

protocol FavBtnDelegate {

  var isFavorited: [Int] { get set }

}
```

In order for this to work the `NewCell` class should conform to the `hasFavBtn` protocol and the HomeViewController should conform to the `FavBtnDelegate` protocol. Like So:

## HomeViewController

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, FavBtnDelegate  {

  var isFavorited = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

  let newCellStr = "NewCell"

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let newCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(newCellStr) as! NewCell

    newCell.delegate = self
    newCell.delegateTableView = tableView

    return newCell
  }
}
```

The important thing to notice here are:

1. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the `delegate` and `delegateTableView` properties for the instance of the `NewCell` class are defined before the `newCell` constant is returned.
2. The `isFavorited` variable is set as described in the `FavBtnDelegate` protocol.

## NewCell.swift

```
class NewCell: UITableViewCell, hasFavBtn {

  var delegate: FavBtnDelegate!
  var delegateTableView: UITableView!

  @IBOutlet weak var favoriteBtn: UIButton!

  let blankStarImg = UIImage(imageLiteral: "blankStar")
  let fullStarImg = UIImage(imageLiteral: "fullStar")

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let blankStarImg = UIImage(imageLiteral: "blankStar")
    favoriteBtn.setBackgroundImage(blankStarImg, forState: .Normal)
  }

  @IBAction func favoriteBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let locationInCell = CGPoint(x: (sender.frame.maxX - sender.frame.minX)/2, y: (sender.frame.maxY - sender.frame.minY)/2)
    let locationInDelegateTableView = convertPoint(locationInCell, toView: delegateTableView)

    if let indexPath = delegateTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInDelegateTableView) {
      if delegate.isFavorited[indexPath.row] == 1 {
        favoriteBtn.setBackgroundImage(fullStarImg, forState: .Normal)
      }
    }
  }
```

As others have said it is here, in that the `UITableViewCell` subclass, that you should define the `@IBAction` for the favorite Button. You can reference the tableView and the `isFavorited` array via the delegate property because in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the value for the `delegateTableView` property was set to the tableView of the HomeViewController and the `delegate` property was set to the HomeViewController instance (using the `self` keyword).

So `favoriteBtnPressed` function finds the center (`CGPoint`) of the button that was pressed and then converts that to the coordinate system of the `delegateTableView` and thereby the tableView in the HomeViewController. Using the converted center of the button in the tableView's coordinate system the code uses an if let binding to safely unwrap the `indexPath` for the converted center. Then using the unwrapped `indexPath` and the `delegate` property you can check whether the HomeViewController's `isFavorited` array value at the given `indexPath` is equal to 1 and adjust the image accordingly.

The swift's protocols and delegation pattern are very powerful and useful for many things. You can read more about them here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Also, note that I put my images in the Assets.xcassets file so I used the imageLiteral initializer to get them.

Hope this helps! If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks a million for your code and work on it @Ike10. I try your approach and come back with the feedback. =D

Comment: That was great. I haven't had that concept about protocol and delegate. I got it now, thanks to you. The code is partially working, but I managed to use HomeVC array in newCell favoriteButtonPressed. In future I will post more questions regarding that, but for now I will spend some time trying to learn and to figure by myself. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You have an action `favoriteAction` in your tableviewcell already. The simple solution to your problem is to **pass the array of possible images into the tableviewcell** when it is dequeued and then you put the code that swaps out the images in the `favoriteAction` IBAction.

If you can't figure out what to do from my description above, I can post some code, but try to figure it out first. I think it's a good learning exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Daniel. Yes, I could, and I did it on the newCell class, but how can I identify the button was pressed in the HomeVC, so that I can work with the arrays queried from database? Sorry if I am not clear, it might be hard to explain for one start at it, and thanks again.

Comment: You don't need to identify the button was pressed in the HomeVC. Instead, you need to make it so the table view cell can work with the arrays queried from the database. Read my answer again, I marked the most important part in bold.

Comment: Looking at your code... You should not have three separate arrays. You need to make a `struct Recipe { var title: String; var imageName: String; var isFavorite: Int }`. Then you can pass the appropriate Recipe object to the table view cell so it can configure itself based on the information in the struct.

Comment: Great, thanks Daniel. I will try this and I come back to tell you.